# Is there an upper limit to Ubuntu One Storage Subscriptions?

Tags: ubuntu-one, storage, mass-storage

At [Ubuntu One Services](https://one.ubuntu.com/services/) it is possible to purchase 20GB of additional storage space for $29.99/year. There is also a box which appears to work as a sort of quantity selector. My question is:
Is there an upper limit to the amount of 20GB subscriptions you can purchase at any one time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is an upper limit. You cannot purchase more than 429.496.728 20-packs. In practice, this is the same as it being unlimited. If you *do* find that you need to purchase more storage than this, talk to us.

Comment: 8-and-a-half Exabytes? Ouch. Thanks.

Comment: 8 exbibytes, minus one byte.

Comment: It's answers like these that make me wish we could favorite answers, as well. You can't really get much more informative than this.

Comment: Even seeing this 1.5 years later this made me smile :D

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no upper limit of how much you can purchase.